# Sort by Date ImmutableJS and Moment()

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs, immutable.js

I have an `array` of `objects`. The objects have the key `date`. The `date` is a `moment` formatted `date`, created like this: `moment('1970-11-11')`.

How do I sort the array by date in ascending/descending order?

That

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => b.get('date') - a.get('date');
```

nor

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => b.get('date').format('DD.MM.YYYY') - a.get('date').format('DD.MM.YYYY'))
```

does not sort it.

Comment: So you subtract string from a string? Does it make any sense to you? Format to a unix time and subtract from an integer.

Comment: @emix didnt think about that... Makes totally sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon me for asking but if I understand correctly you have `moment` objects in that array fully capable of doing date calculations and difference. So if that is the case why not:

```js
var data = [moment('1972-11-11'), moment('1971-11-11'), moment('1973-11-11')]

const result = data.sort((a,b) => a.diff(b))  // change to b.diff(a) for desc

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

As per moment documentation on [**`diff`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/). No need to `date/unix` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => b.get('date').unix() - a.get('date').unix());
```

Comment: is there a way to save it in a new array? Of course it could do something like `const sortedArr = arrayOfObjects` and then `sortedArray.sort((a,b)....`

Comment: You mean this `arrayOfObjects.map(e => ({ ...e, date: e.get('date').unix() })).sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)`?